# Independent threads in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Please consider the following code: Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
    @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        int iterations;
        for (iterations = 0; iterations < 1000; iterations++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                break;
            }
            updateMessage("Iteration " + iterations);
            updateProgress(iterations, 1000);


        //Block the thread for a short time, but be sure
        //to check the InterruptedException for cancellation
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return iterations;
    }
};
```

I am learning JavaFX and wondering, if I have to create 10 independent threads. Say for example, `Thread 1` going to grab the data from MySQL located at an IP `11.11.1.111` , `Thread 2` going to grab the data from MySQL located at an IP `22.22.2.222` , so do I need to write the code starting from `@Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {` for each of the 10 threads, which will be 10 times?

Here is what I have right now:

```
public class MyClass extends Task<Integer> 
 {
         private Class2 QRVC ;

        // my variable declarations here

         @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {




         // Defining logic to grab data from 11.11.1.111
         // Updating the progress bar



         }


         @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {




         // Defining logic to grab data from 22.22.2.222
         // Updating the progress bar



         }

         @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {




         // Defining logic to grab data from 33.33.3.333
         // Updating the progress bar



         }


      }// END OF Class MyClass
```

Comment: The logic of how you want to assign jobs to the thread totally depends on you. You can either write 10 different task or you can have a class extending task and have a logic to separate the functionality of the different threads !

Comment: I see. So I can have 10 different `@Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {` and that's fine, right? I mean I have a class extending `Task<Integer> ` and I am planning to write 10 different ` `@Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {`

Comment: You can't have multiple methods with same definition, Java wont allow it. You can try it ! I would suggest you to have 10 different Task for your 10 different threads !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I have updated my code above with what I am trying to do. You were right, Java isn't allowign me to have methods with same definition.Could you please suggest an example of having/defining multiple tasks for 10 different threads? Thanks

Comment: this code will give you duplicate method, compile time error !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Yes, it is giving me an error. Could you please give me an example of properly doing what I am trying to achieve? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

*I hope you have 10 different progress bars.*

Just make 10 different Classes which extend `Task` and place your logic into individual `call()`

```
public class MyClass1 extends Task<Integer> 
{
    // my variable declarations here

     @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {

     // Defining logic to grab data from 11.11.1.111
     // Updating the progress bar
     }
}

public class MyClass2 extends Task<Integer> 
{
    // my variable declarations here

     @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {

     // Defining logic to grab data from 22.22.2.222
     // Updating the progress bar
     }
}
```

and so on..

Then you can have your

1. Thread1 assigned to MyClass1
2. Thread2 assigned to MyClass2 and so on..

*To assign a Task to a Thread*

```
MyClass1 objClass1 = new MyClass1();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(objClass1);
thread1.start();
```

Comment: `MyClass1` is the class with Java file name that is , `MyClass1.java` So, should I define other classes
inside this class like `classA` , `classB` etc ?For ProgressBars: 

I have defined them in a separate file (Class2.java) in my java package as shown here: https://ideone.com/nnQ16y
and I am calling the  `Class2` in the code above (updated my above code).

Comment: Contd... So basically,the way progress bars
are defined here is based on the value of 10 which is causing to display 10 Progressbars. Do you think that
I will need to define the content I have defined in class `Class2.java` 10 times inside the same classfor 10 different progress bars? 
Please let me know if you need more explanation from me. Thanks @ItachiUchiha

Comment: You have many compile time error's in your code. You don't create an Executor using `QueuyeReaderExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`. Basically, what I can advice you is to start with something very basic. Start with a single Thread and one `Executor` thread pool. Use it and then start increasing your threads, with Tasks !